# What is the name of the song that plays at 5:28 in Noragami Aragoto episode 8?

Tags: music, noragami

What is the name of the song that plays at 5:28 in *Noragami Aragoto* episode 8? I'd like to know the name of the song and where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the piece that plays right when Manabu shows up, this is "M03" from the [*Noragami Aragoto* OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/56225) (disc 2, track 10; only found on the second version, not [the first version](http://vgmdb.net/album/54799)). [Here](https://clyp.it/ughaqbv4?token=d5d34a4a8ac22ef7678f7fccfbc137bc) is a 15-second extract from the beginning of the piece.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same one. Its called Shadow dancing
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AozK3__EX7I&list=PLsD0kaxrSDX5yhnS1PlMP7Hn3Wk_QbPTw&index=16